# ARMCC dependency on ARM processor on the board

Tags: arm, arm9

Is armcc dependent on the type of ARM processor on the hardware board ? Example: while I compile my code (using a make file) where option CPU=CORTEX-A9 is given , it errors out stating argument CortexA9 not permitted for option cpu.  The armcc version I am using is 3.1

Comment: Have you tried `armcc --cpu=list` on the command line to find out what options are supported for that version of the compiler?

Comment: I tried it and it showed a list of ARM processors supported. This helps, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

> Is armcc dependent on the type of ARM processor on the hardware board ?

Yes.

To put it bluntly, an ARM7TDMI and a Cortex-A9 are totally different processors, that happen to share some instructions. Yet both are routinely called 'ARM' chips. Within the Cortexes the differences are smaller, but still significant. You might get by with using a lower number like cortex-a8, but YMMV.

I am not familiar with armcc (google seems to know more than one compiler with this name). Check the release notes of your version to see whether A9 is supported. Maybe you can upgrade to a newer version.